# select from a table if exist otherwise select from another in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I have multiple tables where I select columns from 
Example:

```
select a.name, b.accno, c.bal
from tableA a, tableB b, tableC c
where a.id = d.id and a.id = c.id and a.accno ='12'
```

the issue is tableC may not be available in my schema.
therefore, I would like to check if tableC is available otherwise its should use a.bal in tableA.

pls how do construct my select query to achieve this.
Regards,

Comment: You don't.  You write PL/SQL to check if the table exists, then if it does you execute one query, and if it doesn't you execute a different query.  *(You can google around for exactly how you prefer to do that check, there are a few options.  While you're at it, please learn the explicit `JOIN` syntax rather than using implicit joins with `,`.  The `JOIN` syntax is over 20 years old, but people still insist on teaching the even older antiquated `,` syntax :( It makes me very sad...)*

Comment: This sounds very much like a very, very bad database design. Why would a table be absent? Why could it be replaced by another? Tables are supposed to represent entities, say products, customers, orders. You would never look for the products table, find out it doesn't exist (what the heck?) and select from the customers table instead. You may want to ask another question on how to get your database straight.

Comment: And I am with MatBailie here. Whichever book, tutorial or teacher tells you to use comma-separated joins, dismiss them.

Comment: I appreciate your expertise response on this thanks. Meanwhile, I was actually looking for a workaround for connecting to two difference DB instance. we currently have to databases in two different locations with different DB structure but same field result. therefore, I am just looking for how best I cant switch between two DB based on the location.

Comment: @AfeezOlawale - It doesn't matter.  There is no way for a query to do what you want.  The query will only execute if everything it references actually exists.  You ***must*** either look at a different database structure (where the tables or views, etc, always exist, which you say is not an option), or have two different queries, and run a test to see which query should be executed.

Comment: A strange situation. So you run the query and either you happen to be connected to database A with the table `customer` or to database B with the table `cust` and both have the same columns? Then use SYNONYMs , so you can use the same name.

Comment: If you really wanna do that, I think you could create a function to verify the schema issue and return the value from field you want to.

Comment: @DiegoSouza, I'd like to use the function to validate the schema. So basically I can just issue this query `SELECT OBJECT_NAME, OBJECT_TYPE FROM USER_OBJECTS WHERE OBJECT_NAME = `MY_OBJECT_NAME'.

Comment: @MatBailie : I hear you. It is one thing we insist people here on the internet to use joins the proper way. Believe me, I've even had hard time convincing few of my old colleagues, who still stubbornly use the  `,` syntax and the dreaded `(+)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One workaround I suggest you is:

```
SELECT a.name, 
       b.accno, 
       fn_Bal(a.id, a.bal) as bal
  FROM tableA a 
  JOIN tableB b ON a.id = b.id 
 WHERE a.accno ='12';
```

using a function to handle the "Table or view does not exist" exception:

```
create or replace function fn_bal(a_id in tableA.Id%TYPE,
                                  a_bal in tableA.bal%TYPE)
       return tableA.Bal%TYPE as

   table_does_not_exist exception;
   PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(table_does_not_exist, -942);

   c_bal tableA.Bal%TYPE;

begin

  execute immediate
     'select bal
        from tableC
       where id = :1'
     into c_bal    
    using a_id;

   return c_bal;

exception
  when table_does_not_exist then
     return a_bal;
end;
```